# How do you determine 'magic byte' or version for alt coins?

Tags: altcoin

I'm looking at creating a deterministic wallet for some of the less popular altcoins. Bitcoin has a magic byte of '0488b21e' and litecoin '019da462'. How are these determined or calculated? Also how would I generate these values for other altcoins?

Comment: Note that the 'version byte' is different from the private key prefix. https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/List_of_address_prefixes

Comment: Late response I realize, but see here: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/28380/i-want-to-generate-a-bip32-version-number-for-namecoin-and-other-altcoins/56639#56639

Answer (score 3):

`0x0488B21E` is the extended public key prefix / version bytes (as [described in BIP32](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0032.mediawiki#serialization-format)) and stands for `xpub`. In the same manner, `0x019DA462` stands for `Ltub`.

For bitcoin and litecoin these codes are:

```
Network             Extended private    Version bytes        Extended public    Version bytes
                    key prefix                               key prefix
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------         
Bitcoin main        xprv                0x0488ADE4           xpub               0x0488B21E
Bitcoin testnet     tprv                0x04358394           tpub               0x043587CF
Litecoin main       Ltpv                0x019D9CFE           Ltub               0x019DA462     
Litecoin testnet    ttpv                0x0436EF7D           ttub               0x0436F6E1
```

Comment: How do you go about calculating these values? For example for auroracoin the prefix might be Arub.